# Set the maven project in netbeans 11

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-11

I installed netbeans 11.0 with jdk1.8.0_172. I tried to set a simple maven project.But there is error below.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project etobs-ejb: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

There is no proxy and certificate problem. Also I set a maven project with netbeans 8.2 without error.

Comment: Does set the project mean open an existing project or create a new maven project? Have you tried building with maven directly from the command line?

Comment: Both of them.Neither open an existing or create new a maven project have same error.I didn't try command line. But I will. Thanks